# Change layout of page using css only (without changing DOM placement)

Tags: html, css

I have a structure which cannot be changed due to some reasons.Here is the structure:

```
<h1>heading</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecadipiem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet]consectetur adipiscing elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sitg elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Se</p>
<div style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #f1f1f1">container</div>
```

[image]

I want to get this particular layout using CSS only, ie. no positions, negative margins etc. The HTML elements will remain in same flow - `h1`, `p` and `div`. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: So all you want is to float the div left? Then `float: left` should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you. The main thing is to put `float: left` on the left hand `div`.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #wrapper {
        width: 90%;   
    }
    #container {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: #666;   
        margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    }
    H1 {
        font: bold 2em arial;
    }
    P {
        background-color: #ccc;  
    }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">#container</div>
    <h1>Heading</h1>

    <p>
        Some text.
    </p>
</div>
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/mtRwC/)

Comment: Sorry but i cannot change HTMl elements' placement and they don't even have a parent because... they will just repeat themselves to form tupples.

Comment: I don't even know if this is possible or not!!

Comment: Apologies, I missed that you couldn't change structure. In that case, the layout is not possible. The 'container' div must come first for it to appear at the top of the text. You could position it absolutely, but this would require a parent element positioned relatively, and would also mean the container div would have to stay the exact same size every time it was used.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that in CSS only! :)

I know this is an old question, but its a fun challenge. The trick is to create a pseudo element before the h1 that floats left to create the space for the container div.

I'm sure there are many other ways to do this...

```css
div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
h1::before {
  content:'';
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>heading</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecadipiem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet]consectetur adipiscing elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sitg elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. SeLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Se</p>
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background:#f1f1f1">container</div>
```